# Why compiler treats System.Object as null when its set to False

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics

I wrote a generic method to retrieve single values from database (MSSQL Server).
I encountered into a case that I need to get a `Boolean` value from DB.

As you can see in the code below, a `Object` local field (`IsExist`) gets the result.

When the value in DB is False `GenericScalar()` method return False (as it should)
and the condition: `if (IsExist == null)` in `GetWanLineDisconnectionData()` is true and the return block is executing, even though IsExist is False and not null.

Why is that?

How can I overcome this problem?

```
private void GetWanLineDisconnectionData()
{
    string q = "SELECT WanLineDiscconection FROM AdditionalProjectsData WHERE SpCall= " + "'" + spCall + "'";
    object IsExist = Orange.ProjectManagment.DAL.Database.GenericScalar<object>(q);
    if (IsExist == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (bool.Parse(IsExist) == true) {
        RadWanDiscYes.Checked = true;
    } else {
        RadWanDiscNo.Checked = true;
    }    
}
```

Database method:

```
public static T GenericScalar<T>(string query)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(sqlConnString);
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    try
    {
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)result;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection(ref connection);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
maybe a few screen shoots will better demonstrate it:
(note that: `GetWanLineDisconnectionData()` is written in VB.NET and `GenericScalar()` is written in C# on a different project in the solution):

1. in the beginning `IsExist` is nothing (null).
   [image]
2. the query finds one row and the value of the bool column WanLineDiscconection  is false and `IsExist` is set to false as it should be. 
   [image]
3. here is the problem, the program enters the if block and `IsExist` is not nothing (null).
   [image]

Comment: Its null for no value but DBNull.Value for a db NULL btw.

Comment: Please use `using` blocks, your snippet is a textbook sample of how to mess it up by trying to do it yourself. And don't `throw ex;`. Use `throw;` only, the alternative messes up the stack trace.

Comment: What is the type of `WanLineDiscconection`?

Comment: @nvoigt True, but in this case it would be better to omit the catch block altogether as it serves no function (except destroying the stack trace).

Comment: @HimBromBeere its boolean

Comment: So why not use `GenericScalar<bool>` if you know the type returned from the database? Then `default(T)` will evalauet to `false`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that what i did in the beginning, so when the column is null default(T) returns false and not null (as it should, false is default of boolean) so i have changed the data type to an object because i need null and not false, please see my last comment to CodeCaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `foo` in `object foo = false` is definitely not `null`, so the premise in your title is incorrect.

`ExecuteScalar()` returns `null` when there are no rows. In that case, the method `GenericScalar()` return `default(T)`, which for `object` will be `null`.

How to solve this depends on what your data looks like. You probably want to represent the result in a nullable int, or `int?` instead of `object`:

```
var exists = Orange.ProjectManagment.DAL.Database.GenericScalar<int?>(q);
RadWanDiscYes.Checked = exists.GetValueOrDefault() > 0;
```

See [How does GetValueOrDefault work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626329/how-does-getvalueordefault-work), [What is the default value of the nullable type "int?" (including question mark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153832/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-nullable-type-int-including-question-mark).

Aside from that: you generally also don't want to write handy wrappers around database queries, because you're reinventing the wheel poorly, opening up your application to SQL injection. That being said, there's a lot more going wrong in that method, including but not limited to not disposing your database connection and rethrowing exceptions without their stacktrace.

Comment: Why not use `exists.HasValue`? Seems easier than querying the value and determing if that one is greater zero, doesn´t it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere as stated in the answer, I don't know what their data looks like. `(int?)0` has a value, but might mean `false`.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for your response and code review notes, but there is a row, and the value of the boolean column `WanLineDiscconection` is false, hence `IsExist` value is false (not null) and it is the expected result of the query, the problem is inside `GetWanLineDisconnectionData()` method: the condition `(IsExist == null)` treat it as null and not as false like it should be and the if block is executed (and it should not be excuted) , i know that sound strange, i have tested it a few times and i cant understand why.

Comment: another thing that maybe is important to mention, `GetWanLineDisconnectionData()` is written in VB.NET and `GenericScalar()` is written in C# on a different project in the solution.

Comment: @jonathana you're probably debugging a release build, and the debugger is lying about the line that leaves the method.

Answer (score 0):

You´re mixing *compile*-time and *runtime* information. Whilst `GenericScalar<object>(q)` is an information that exists at compile-time the type returned from `ExecuteScalar` at *compile*-time is just `object`. You expect it to be of type `boolean`, which might or might not be true for your specific case. However this is not relevant to the compiler.

In short that means that `T` actually is `object`, not whatever you expect it to be from your database. And as CodeCaster allready mentioned the default-value for `object` is just `null`.

Si I´d suggest to use `GenericScalar<bool>` instead of `GenericScalar<object>` because you seem to know what your query actually returns - in your case a `bool`. Then `default(T)` evaluates to `false`, not to `null`.

Comment: thank you for the response, i have already tried it with bool type. please see my comment to CodeCaster answer.