# Coalesce with property of nullable object?

Tags: c#, nullable

Hello is there any way formulate a condition like the one below ? 
If field is null then false else field.Property ?

```
class Node
{
    public bool IsFilled;
}

class Holder
{
    Node nodeBuffer;
    public bool IsFilled => this.nodeBuffer?.IsFilled ?? false; 
}
```

How can i say something like `if nodeBuffer is  null then false else nodeBuffer.IsFilled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.nodeBuffer?.IsFilled` returns a `Nullable<T>` so you can just use [`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626329/how-does-getvalueordefault-work) method on it so it will be `false` if `null`.

So your property definition will look like below:

```
public bool IsFilled => (this.nodeBuffer?.IsFilled).GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator) which works with `Nullable<bool>`

```
public bool IsFilled => this.nodeBuffer?.IsFilled == true;
```

Nullable types support all operators that their non-nullable type support, that's called: [lifted operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators)